How to get value of column from complex json while creating ADF pipeline
I have a complex json coming from cosmos db with a fsid and fpid in string format .
I am moving the data to sql where it is integer.
I am unable to get the value read from cosmos for this particular column and convert to int.
sample JSON:
{
    "id": "test",
    "documentType": "testing",
    "content": {
        "id": "test1",
       
      
        "current": {
            "fsid": "PP",
            "fpid": "2021",         
            "publishStatus": "Draft"
        },
        "released": null,
        "name": "PPGG"
    },
    "date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
    "_ts": 111
}

Objective:

Get value for fsid and convert it into integer to pass SQL sink based on condition.eg if fsid is PP,get int value 1,if fsid is QQ,get value 2
convert date to sql datatime format

Tried:
I tried using derived column toInteger(content.current.fsid) but it is reading a null.
Also,i tried using cast but I am not getting the column name itself and only showing top level columns.
Any suggestion please ?


Get value for fsid and convert it into integer to pass SQL sink based on condition.eg if fsid is PP,get int value 1,if fsid is QQ,get value 2

As your fsid is in string for like PP or any other characters If you try to convert into integer, it will read sting characters as null.
As you convert it to integer based on condition, so you need to use derived column with IIF condition or case statement as below:
Expression:
fsid : iif(content.current.fsid=='PP',1,iif(content.current.fsid=='QQ',2,0))
//if fsid == PP then 1 else check fsid == QQ if it true then 2 if both conditions are not matching then 0


Data preview:


convert date to sql datatime format

You can use cast transformation to convert date into your required format as below:


Thanks I found the column using Select and then using Case. I used your suggestion to cast date and it worked.Thanks
